# Definite integrals involving the product of arbitrary Bessel function and arbitrary power of x

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

Is there a general formula for the following definite integral:
$\int^{a}_{b}J_m(\lambda_{mi}x)x^ndx=?$
Where **n** and **m** are arbitrary natural numbers and $\lambda_{mi}$ is i-th zero of m-th Bessel function $J_m$ and integration interval is $[a,b]\subset[0,1]$.
If it exists, please show how it is derived.

Comment: For the antiderivative try https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+BesselJ%5Bm,+BesselJZero%5Bm,+i%5Dx%5D+x%5En

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, Wolfram assumes that $i$ is the imaginary unit, I think it's better to use another letter. Though the answer doesn't change, apparently

Comment: @YuriyS. Thanks to mention it ! Being almost blind, there are "small" things like that  I can miss. Cheers.